# Is there any way to get the Draconic Claw feat without losing BAB?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, sorcerer, e6

*Races of the Dragon* has a very interesting feat in Draconic Claw (p. 102), which gives you a pair of claw attacks as well as the ability to make a claw attack as a swift action in any turn in which you cast a spell as a standard action. This combines very nicely with, for example, Snap Kick from *Tome of Battle*.<sup>1</sup>

However, I primarily play [E6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97252/4563), and Snap Kick requires BAB +6. Meanwhile, Draconic Claw, as well as its prerequisite Draconic Heritage, requires sorcerer level 1st, so I run into a problem: I cannot quality for Draconic Claw without taking a level in a class that does not get full BAB, which prevents me from achieving +6 in 6 levels.

The first thing that came to mind was actually being a dragon—as absurd as taking Draconic Heritage as a dragon would be—since those cast spells as sorcerers. But unfortunately, [you don’t actually qualify as being a member of the class you cast as without taking at least one level of that class](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26985/4563). So even a dragon would still, technically, require a level of sorcerer—and thus losing BAB.

So, is there any way to get Draconic Claw without losing BAB, or otherwise still be able to take Snap Kick in an E6 environment?<sup>2</sup> Any Wizards of the Coast-published material, *Dragon* or *Dungeon* magazine material, or “official” E6 material may be used. Variant classes, alternate class features, and so on, are acceptable, but entire variant systems—such as *Unearthed Arcana*’s gestalt leveling or generic classes—cannot be used. Let’s also leave out methods of cheesing yourself to *divine power* and then claiming you get a bonus feat with that active—I know it can be done but it’s not an interesting solution to this problem.

1. <sub>With thanks and credit to @forrestfire for discovering this combo.</sub>
2. <sub>And under no circumstances is the answer to any *other* question appropriate here—I want to to accomplish Draconic Claw and Snap Kick in E6, not any other combination of options that may or may not approximate similar functionality. I have asked this question, not any other one, and am therefore interested in answers to this question and not to any other one.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Take first Dragontouched then Draconic Heritage

The general feat **Dragontouched** has as its sole prerequisite Charisma 11, and the final sentence of its benefit says that "you can select draconic feats as if you were a sorcerer of your character level" (*Dragon Magic* 18–19). Taking the feat Dragontouched then the feat **Draconic Heritage** (*Races of the Dragon* 102–3) allows a creature that has available a racial bonus feat to take the feat **Draconic Claw** (*Races of the Dragon* 102) as early as level 3, or as early as level 1 in a campaign that uses flaws. Thus such a character can take classes that possess full base attack throughout her career.

---

***Note:*** The benefit of the feat Draconic Claw begins, "You gain **a claw** attack. You can make a natural attack with **two claws**, dealing damage based on your size as if you were truly a dragon…" (emphasis mine). Ask the DM what this means as there's no errata for Races of the Dragon.

Comment: Hah! I could have sworn we checked that, but both Kryan and I clearly repeatedly missed it. Nice catch!

Comment: How can you take Draconic Claw on level one? Even with a Human, you only get two feats, and you need 3: Dragontouched, Draconic Heritage and Draconic Claw. What am I missing?

Comment: @András You missed nothing; I did. All fixed. Thank you for your interest. (My inner game designer must really think that this shouldn't require expending this amount of resources!)